# How to express " haven't you slept yet?"

Tags: expressions

I am a Chinese and I want to express the following concept:

It is midnight, someone   is still awake and  I am surprised.

How can I say in  American English?

> "oh! you haven't sleep?" or "you don't go to bed?"

Comment: Are they in bed but not asleep or are they still up and doing things?

Comment: this is not the key, i just want to know how to express it in English

Comment: In the UK, at least, the logically stupid "Aren't you asleep yet?" would be used almost without exception.

Comment: @CaiChuck - The reason I asked is that I would say different things in those situations.   I might say, “what’s the matter? can’t fall asleep?” (if you think they want to sleep but are unable to) or, “ Hey, why aren’t you asleep yet?” (if you caught them reading in bed instead of sleeping)) But, “Hey, why aren’t you in bed yet?” if they are still up and doing things.

Comment: Is "Are you still up?!" or "You're still up?!" in a surprised tone usable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the Expression which they use.

Mostly people use *you haven't gone to sleep yet?*

Comment: can you tell me the right answer?

Comment: updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another is: "Oh! Why are you not asleep yet?"